# How to run try.freemarker.apache.org locally

Tags: freemarker

https://try.freemarker.apache.org/ is down, or more likely, it's not publicly available anymore as I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. It's been such a great tool to quickly check syntax as I often send FreeMarker snippets to others.

Is it possible to run this site locally?

Comment: Wrong site to ask... See [help/on-topic]

Comment: Stack Overflow has the largest community of Freemarker users, which is why I wanted to ask here first.

Also, to future visitors, my original question was asking why it was down, not how to run it locally, but I'm fine to run it locally with the answer given below.

Comment: well, the original question was phrased like a report that a server is down, which is off-topic. After the edit, the question changed dramatically. It's still quite broad, but closer to being on-topic here than the original report

Comment: It's up again, check: https://try.freemarker.apache.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update (2021-05-05): Site is up: https://try.freemarker.apache.org/

---

I found the source code on github along with build and deploy instructions:
https://github.com/apache/freemarker-online-tester

You can follow the instructions (requires Java 1.8) to get this tool running locally on your machine and never deal with availability issue again!. I tested it:

[image]

### Steps

- Clone the repository `https://github.com/apache/freemarker-online-tester.git`
- Open cmd in project folder root and run command: `gradlew build`
- Wait until gradle wrapper installs gradle and all dependencies then builds, here's the expected output:

```
    :compileJava
    :processResources
    :classes
    :jar
    :assemble
    :compileTestJava
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/javassist/javassist/3.20.0-GA/javassist-3.20.0-GA.pom
    :processTestResources
    :testClasses
    :test
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.8/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.8.pom
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.build/0.7.8/org.jacoco.build-0.7.8.pom
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.8/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.8.jar
    :jacocoTestReport
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.ant/0.7.8/org.jacoco.ant-0.7.8.pom
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.8/org.jacoco.core-0.7.8.pom
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.8/org.jacoco.report-0.7.8.pom
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.1/asm-debug-all-5.1.pom
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/5.1/asm-parent-5.1.pom
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.ant/0.7.8/org.jacoco.ant-0.7.8.jar
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.8/org.jacoco.core-0.7.8.jar
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.8/org.jacoco.report-0.7.8.jar
    Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.1/asm-debug-all-5.1.jar
    :check
    :shadowJar
    :build
    
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

- Run `gradlew shadowJar`
  Expected output:

```
$ gradlew shadowJar
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:shadowJar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.413 secs
```

- Start the application, run command: `java -jar build/libs/freemarker-online-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server src/main/resources/freemarker-online.yml`

Here is a screenshot from the running server console:
[image]

- Visit your Online FreeMarker Template Tester's link:
  `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a shot.